# Deploy multiple instances of a Virtual Machine in Azure

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I have a Virtual Machine, let's call it Ceres, which is currently running in Azure. I would like to have two copies of Ceres running. Is it possible to simply create another identical instance of this same server in Azure?

I notice in the literature for Microsoft Azure references to "multiple instances" but I cannot find a simple way to start up two instances of the same server.

The virtual machine in question is running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: +1 for great question and "Ceres" =)

Answer (score 4):

you need to capture your vm as an image template and use it to deploy all the machines you want from it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/